# Isn't available 3.6.11 Python Version in anaconda?

Tags: python-3.x, macos, anaconda, python-3.6

[Problem]
I want to use **python version 3.6.11** in **Mac** OS.
I tried to below things, but there is 3.9.7 when enter `python -V` & `python3 -V` & `python --version`.

[tried to]
I'm using **anaconda** and I've been checked available python versions.
However, only 3.6.11 version dosen't exist.

And, I've tried to **install python 3.6.11** in python install in python download site.
[URL is here] : (https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

In additional, I've downloaded python 3.6.11 by using **brew**.

[question]
So, How can I do to use python 3.6.11 in Mac (M1) & Anaconda environment?

Comment: Can you tell us why you need such a specific old release?

Comment: uninstall the new version if you really dont want it.

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.6 has reached end-of-life and is no longer supported.

The latest (security bugfix) release was 3.6.15, which is available [here](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3615/) as a source code release only.

If you have installed 3.6.11 using `brew`, you could use it in several ways:

- Change `python3` (which is probably a symbolic link) to point to the 3.6 executable.
- In the `#!`-line of your scripts, call the python 3.6 executable explicitly.