# No Python 3.6 available in conda search -f python

Tags: python, conda

If I run:

```
conda search -f python
```

There is no Python <3.8 available... how can I get it?

The output that I get is the following:

```
python                         3.8.5 h05baefb_8_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.8.6 h12cc5a1_1_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.8.6 h12cc5a1_2_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.8.6 h12cc5a1_3_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.8.6 h12cc5a1_4_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.8.6 h12cc5a1_5_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.8.6 h3098bc4_0_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.8.8 h12cc5a1_0_cpython  conda-forge         
python                        3.8.10 h69cb8a9_0_cpython  conda-forge         
python                        3.8.10 hab31e5c_2_cpython  conda-forge         
python                        3.8.10 hf9733c0_1_cpython  conda-forge         
python                        3.8.12 hab31e5c_0_cpython  conda-forge         
python                        3.8.12 hab31e5c_1_cpython  conda-forge         
python                        3.8.12 hab31e5c_2_cpython  conda-forge         
python                        3.8.12 hab31e5c_3_cpython  conda-forge         
python                        3.8.12 hd949e87_1_cpython  conda-forge         
python                        3.8.12 hd949e87_2_cpython  conda-forge         
python                        3.8.12 hd949e87_3_cpython  conda-forge         
python                        3.8.13 h7e095e3_0_cpython  conda-forge         
python                        3.8.13 hd3575e6_0_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.9.0 h4b4120c_5_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.9.0 hd001b3a_0_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.9.0 hd001b3a_1_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.9.0 hd001b3a_2_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.9.0 hd001b3a_3_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.9.0 hf1b0709_4_cpython  conda-forge         
python                      3.9.1rc1 h4b4120c_0_cpython  conda-forge         
python                      3.9.1rc1 h4b4120c_1_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.9.1 h4b4120c_0_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.9.1 hcbd9b3a_1_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.9.1 hcbd9b3a_2_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.9.1 hcbd9b3a_3_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.9.1 hcbd9b3a_4_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.9.1 hcbd9b3a_5_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.9.2 hcbd9b3a_0_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.9.4 h5b20da3_0_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.9.5 h54d631c_0_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.9.6 h54d631c_0_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.9.6 h54d631c_1_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.9.7 h54d631c_0_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.9.7 h54d631c_1_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.9.7 h54d631c_2_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.9.7 h54d631c_3_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.9.7 hc0da0df_3_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.9.9 h43b31ca_0_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.9.9 h70c1b39_0_cpython  conda-forge         
python                        3.9.10 h38ef502_0_cpython  conda-forge         
python                        3.9.10 h38ef502_1_cpython  conda-forge         
python                        3.9.10 h38ef502_2_cpython  conda-forge         
python                        3.9.10 hd16f9c5_0_cpython  conda-forge         
python                        3.9.10 hd16f9c5_1_cpython  conda-forge         
python                        3.9.10 hd16f9c5_2_cpython  conda-forge         
python                        3.9.12 h14b404e_1_cpython  conda-forge         
python                        3.9.12 hfc7342c_1_cpython  conda-forge         
python                        3.9.13 h96fcbfb_0_cpython  conda-forge         
python                        3.9.13 hc596b02_0_cpython  conda-forge         
python                        3.10.0 h43b31ca_1_cpython  conda-forge         
python                        3.10.0 h43b31ca_2_cpython  conda-forge         
python                        3.10.0 h43b31ca_3_cpython  conda-forge         
python                        3.10.0 h70c1b39_1_cpython  conda-forge         
python                        3.10.0 h70c1b39_2_cpython  conda-forge         
python                        3.10.0 h70c1b39_3_cpython  conda-forge         
python                        3.10.1 h43b31ca_0_cpython  conda-forge         
python                        3.10.1 h43b31ca_1_cpython  conda-forge         
python                        3.10.1 h43b31ca_2_cpython  conda-forge         
python                        3.10.1 h70c1b39_0_cpython  conda-forge         
python                        3.10.1 h70c1b39_1_cpython  conda-forge         
python                        3.10.1 h70c1b39_2_cpython  conda-forge         
python                        3.10.2 h38ef502_1_cpython  conda-forge         
python                        3.10.2 h38ef502_2_cpython  conda-forge         
python                        3.10.2 h38ef502_3_cpython  conda-forge         
python                        3.10.2 h38ef502_4_cpython  conda-forge         
python                        3.10.2 h43b31ca_0_cpython  conda-forge         
python                        3.10.2 h70c1b39_0_cpython  conda-forge         
python                        3.10.2 hd16f9c5_1_cpython  conda-forge         
python                        3.10.2 hd16f9c5_2_cpython  conda-forge         
python                        3.10.2 hd16f9c5_3_cpython  conda-forge         
python                        3.10.2 hd16f9c5_4_cpython  conda-forge         
python                        3.10.4 h14b404e_0_cpython  conda-forge         
python                        3.10.4 hfc7342c_0_cpython  conda-forge         
python                        3.10.5 h4eee789_0_cpython  conda-forge         
python                        3.10.5 h71ab1a4_0_cpython  conda-forge
```

Comment: The output should start with `Loading channels: done` `# Name  Version  Build  Channel`.  Is it possible that the top lines of the output have just scrolled out of the range of your terminal window?

Comment: @slothrop I've just posted the list, the first lines are  ```conda search -f python 
Loading channels: done
# Name                       Version           Build  Channel             
python                         3.8.5 h05baefb_8_cpython  conda-forge ```

Comment: Thanks, I see!  It could be a Mac thing then: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71567667/isnt-available-3-6-11-python-version-in-anaconda

Comment: @slothrop I'm starting to have apple, just because nobody supports this platform...

Comment: For users wanting minimal configuration finicking, I recommend installing a **osx-64** version of Miniforge rather than the native (**osx-arm64**) one, and will probably continue recommending this for another year. The package support is still sparse, and emulation works mostly without issue. As an aside, this reminds me so much of the 32-bit to 64-bit transition in the late 00's. It took several years before there was a smooth user experience for native 64-bit. However, Apple could be doing more to help community projects like Conda Forge, Bioconda, Bioconductor support their platform.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70219965/570918), Conda only has support for Python 3.8+ on the **osx-arm64** platform. However, you can still create **osx-64** environments and these will (seamlessly) run in emulation.

To *search* alternative platforms, one can use the `--subdir, --platform` argument to specify that:

```bash
conda search --subdir osx-64 python=3.6
```

or set the `subdir` configuration temporarily through the `CONDA_SUBDIR` environment variable:

```bash
CONDA_SUBDIR=osx-64 conda search python=3.6
```

Consult [the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70205633/570918) for how to *create environments* using these versions.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I am seeing. You may want to add some channels and use `conda search python`:

```
$ conda search python
Loading channels: done
# Name                       Version           Build  Channel             
python                         1.0.1               0  conda-forge         
python                           1.2               0  conda-forge         
...
python                      3.6.0rc1               0  conda-forge         
python                         3.6.0               0  conda-forge         
python                         3.6.0               1  conda-forge   
...      
python                        3.6.13 haf480d7_1_cpython  conda-forge         
python                        3.6.13 haf480d7_2_cpython  conda-forge         
python                        3.6.15 haf480d7_0_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.7.0   h145921a_1002  conda-forge         
python                         3.7.0   h145921a_1003  conda-forge         
python                         3.7.0   h145921a_1004  conda-forge  
...
   
python                        3.10.5 hdaaf3db_0_cpython  conda-forge         
python                        3.10.5 hdd68b96_0_cpython  conda-forge
```

```
$ cat ~/.condarc
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - bioconda
  - defaults
```

**NOTE:**

You can also search for exact versions, for example:

```
$ conda search 'python=3.6'
Loading channels: done
# Name                       Version           Build  Channel             
python                       3.6.0a3               0  conda-forge         
python                       3.6.0a4               0  conda-forge         
...
python                        3.6.13 haf480d7_2_cpython  conda-forge         
python                        3.6.15 haf480d7_0_cpython  conda-forge
```

Comment: strange because if I create an env with python 3.6 i get: ```Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

ResolvePackageNotFound: 
  - python=3.6.0
``` any idea? maybe because I'm on macos?